# Can't create table with error no : 150

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am using the below create table to create a posts table in mysql :

```
mysql> create table posts(
    -> post_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    -> author_id INT NOT NULL,
    -> title varchar(50),
    -> post TEXT,
    -> data DATE,
    -> FOREIGN KEY (author_id)
    -> REFERENCES authors(author_id)
    -> ON DELETE RESTRICT)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

But i always get this error:
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'myFirstBlog.posts' (errno: 150)

The describe of my authors table is as follows:

```
mysql> desc authors;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| author_id | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_name | varchar(16) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password  | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can someone please help me with where the error is .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given that the create statement of your authors table would look like this: `create table authors (author_id int not null auto_increment primary key, user_name varchar(16));`, I can not verify your problem. Your statement works fine for me.

Comment: Your authors table is InnoDB, too, right?

Comment: No i guess not . I just ran this  query :

Comment: what is the encoding type of two tables ?

Comment: if its not the same innoDB you will get above error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table posts(
     post_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     author_id INT NOT NULL,
     title varchar(50),
     post TEXT,
     data DATE,
     FOREIGN KEY (author_id)
     REFERENCES authors(author_id)
     ON DELETE RESTRICT
     )ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Kindly make datatype of both table's column same.
authors(author_id) and post(author_id)

**Or**

Make authors table first and then execute above query.

I had tried below query it's worked for me.

```
create table posts(
     post_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     author_id INT NOT NULL,
     title varchar(50),
     post TEXT,
     data DATE,
     FOREIGN KEY (author_id)
     REFERENCES labels(id)
     ON DELETE RESTRICT
     )ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Hope this will helps.